# python xrange with 0*l to l

Tags: python, xrange

this is what am trying to do :

```
l = 4
length = 10**l #10000
for x in xrange(length): 
   password = str(username)+str("%02d"%x) #but here instead of 2 i want it to be l
```

as you can see i want to control the format string with a variable witch i could do on my own 
i tried to do it like this :

```
password = str(username)+str("%0"+str(l)+"d"%x)
```

but it gives me an error telling me that : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: what is `"d"%x` is it `"%d"%x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` format specifier:

```
>>> '-%0*d' % (4, 9)
'-0009'
>>> '-%0*d' % (9, 9)
'-000000009'
```

According to the [String formatting operations documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> Minimum field width (optional). **If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the
>   actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values,** and
>   the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional
>   precision.

Alternative using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '-{:0{}}'.format(9, 4)
'-0009'
>>> '-{:0{}}'.format(9, 9)
'-000000009'
```

Comment: i actually want to loop from like 0000 to 9999, but i want the length to be controlled by a variable it may be from 00 99 ..etc

Comment: @s4my, The answer is for string-formatting part (body of the `for` loop). You can reuse your `for` loop with my answer.

Comment: @s4my, `for x in xrange(length): password = '%s-%0*d' % (username, l, x)`